# jQuery animations conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I tried to use jQuery animation to animate a div's content and reset everything to default using a close button. The problem is here that after clicking on close button and resetting everything to default, the first animation starts again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".order-b").click(function(){
        $(".order-t").animate({top:'30%'}, "slow" );
        $(".order-c").animate({opacity: '1', top:'70%'}, "slow" );
        $(".order-ca").delay('800').animate({opacity:'1'}, "slow" );
      }).clearQueue().stop();

      $(".order-c").click(function(){
        $(".order-ca").animate({opacity:'0'}, "fast" );
        $(".order-t").delay('800').animate({top:'52%'}, "slow" );
        $(".order-c").delay('800').animate({opacity: '0', top:'70%'}, "slow" );

      });
});

<div class="process-bars">
   <div class="process-bar order-b">
      <div class="process-title order-t">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          <h1>Order</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="process-caption order-ca">
          <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="process-close order-c">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
      </div>                                         
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: oder-c is inside order-b, so it will trigger the order-b click, try preventPropergation http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class .order-b is within the class .order-c so the event click will always trigger on click into the div . 
You have to use  http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Your div with the class

```
"process-bar order-b"
```

is the parent div from

```
"process-close order-c"
```

So your "click"-event from the order-b also fires, if you klick at the order-c.

You have to put that child with the class order-c outside. not in the div with the class "order-b".